# A Lebesgue measure question involving a dense subset of R, translates of a measurable set, etc.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\{b_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and let $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable set such that $m(D \triangle (D + b_n))=0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (here, the $\triangle$ denotes the symmetric difference of the two sets, $D+ b_n = \{d + b_n : d \in D\}$, and $m$ stands for the Lebesgue measure). Prove that $m(D)=0$ or $m(D^c)=0$ (here $D^c$ is the complement of $D$ in  $\mathbb{R}$).

I am having trouble getting a proof off the ground! In particular, it is not clear to me how and where the dense hypothesis would come in. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

1) $m(D \Delta (D + x))$ is a continuous function of $x$.

2) If $x$ and $y$ are Lebesgue points of $D$ and $D^c$ respectively, what can you say about $m(D \Delta (D + x - y))$?

Comment: I am engaging measure theory for the first time, and I am unfamiliar with the term "Lebesgue point of a set," and thus I don't see the connection you intend in 2). Could you clarify what this term means? Then perhaps I can make sense of 2).

Comment: Actually I should have said "point of density" - or "Lebesgue point of the indicator function".  The Lebesgue density theorem says that for almost every $x \in D$, $\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \frac{m(D \cap (x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon))}{2\varepsilon} = 1$.

Comment: For a further hint, if $m(D \cap (x-\varepsilon, x+\varepsilon))$  and $m(D^c \cap (y-\varepsilon, y+\varepsilon))$ are both very close to $2 \varepsilon$, what can you say about $m(D \Delta (D + x - y))$?

Comment: I am not yet familiar enough with Lebesgue differentiation to make the argument go through. However, a fellow graduate student in my program suggested that the above result follows via contradiction by making smart uses of an interesting result:

Let $A$ be Lebesgue measurable, with $m(A)>0$ (here $m$ denotes the Lebesgue measure). Then for any $0<\rho<1$, there exists an open interval $I$ such that $m(A \cap I)> \rho \cdot m(I)$.  I was wondering if you would be up for offering some hints on how this argument might proceed.

Comment: An even further hint: using the Lebesgue density theorem, there are $x \in D$ and $y \in D^c$ and $\epsilon > 0$ such that
$m(D \cap (x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon)) > \epsilon$ and $m(D^c \cap (y-\epsilon,y+\epsilon)) > \epsilon$. What does this say about
$m((D - x) \cap(-\epsilon,\epsilon))$ and $m((D^c-y) \cap (-\epsilon,\epsilon))$?  What can you conclude about $m((D-x) \cap (D^c - y))$?