Proof verification: Showing a measurable set that is translation invariant under rationals is either null or of full measure
Suppose that $E$ is measurable and $E+q \subseteq E$ for all $q \in \mathbb Q$. Show that either $m(E)=0$ or $m(E^c)=0$.
I wanted to try proving the statement using the Lebesgue Density theorem. This is my attempt:
If $m(E)=0$, there is nothing to show. So suppose that $m(E)>0$. For almost every $x\in E$, we have that
$$\lim_{r\to 0} \frac{m(E\cap [x-r,x+r]}{2r} = 1$$
In particular, for  any $\epsilon>0$ there is some $\delta>0$ such that for any $q< \delta$,
$$\frac{m(E \cap [x,x+q])}{2q} -1\leq \frac{m(E\cap [x-q,x+q])}{2q} -1 <\epsilon$$
which implies that
$$\frac{m(E \cap [x,x+q])}{2q} \geq 1-\epsilon \text{ which further implies that } m(E\cap[x,x+q]) \geq 1-\epsilon$$
We can suppose that $q\in \mathbb Q$ and that $\delta<1$, so that we further get that
$$m(E\cap [x, x+1]) \geq 1-\epsilon$$
and
since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary,
$$m(E\cap [x,x+1])=1$$
On the other hand, by hypothesis for all $q\in \mathbb Q$,
$$1=m(E+q \cap [x+q, x+1+q]) \leq m(E\cap [x+q,x+1 +q]) \leq1$$
which further gives us that $m(E\cap[x+q,x+q+1])=1$ for all $q\in \mathbb Q$, i.e. $E$ is of full measure.
I don't know if I am overlooking something, as I have been told to try using other methods instead?
I appreciate any revisions or suggestions!

How did you get $m(E\cap[x,x+q]) \geq 1-\epsilon$ from $\frac{m(E \cap [x,x+q])}{2q} \geq 1-\epsilon$?

I overlooked that part. Perhaps I can patch that by having $q \geq 1/2$?

You need $q<\delta$ and there is no control on $\delta$.

Thanks for that! I guess I need to come up with another direction.

See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1403277/show-that-a-given-set-has-full-measure-or-measure-0
